# Mini pageLayout popup not displaying for Extenal Object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-connect, mini-page-layout, light-application-object

Mini page layout is working fine in Salesforce Standard & Custom objects.
But, I need to create Mini PageLayout for Exernal Object, which acts when hOver to the link of the record in child record It'l  popup a mini page with respective record

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is mini page layout only work for external objects when you hover over **'recent items'** and not lookup fields or child records. I would love to be proven wrong here. 
So you might have to either consider this as system limitation now or go for something custom (which is not a feasible approach here).